# select recursion with one option selected php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, recursion, select, dropdown

I have recursion function which populates data on my select drop down.

How can I pass a value that, if it matches with any value on drop down, gets selected?

this is function on my model:

```
function get_all_cat($parent,$level=0,$s){
        $ui = '';
        $this->db->order_by($this->id, $this->order);
        $this->db->where('parent',$parent);
        $query=$this->db->get($this->table)->result();
        
        foreach ($query as $qu) {
        if($s==$qu->id){
        $y = 'selected';
        }
        $repeat = str_repeat('--', $level);
        
        $ui .= '<option value="'. $qu->id .'" '.$y.' >' .$repeat. $qu->title.'</option>';
        
        $new_level = $level+1;
        $ui .= '' .$this->get_all_cat($qu->id,$new_level) .'';
        }
        return $ui;
}
```

and here is my select option in the view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select name="category" class="form-control chosen-select">
        <option value="">Any Category</option>
        <?php
        $cat =   $this->Dbc_categories_model->get_all_cat(0,0,$this-session->userdata('clicked_id');
        echo $cat;
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: why did you tag this [tag:recursion]?, also where is your problem? Could you please explain, there is no controller in the mix, so how does the view get it's data from?

Comment: oh, just saw, you call the model function directly from the view....That's kind of breaking the MVC concept of the framework

Comment: its possible to call the model function directly from view in codeigniter. the real problems is that the select dropdown  is generated from database category table recursively. now i want when i click the option it should be sent to controller and put that value in a session now when returning back to the view and calling again the recursion function if any category id is equal to the id in session that id should be selected.

Comment: I didn't say you cannot call a model from the view, it's possible, but against the concept of CI. Anyway, what you want to do, depends on your recurses. A php + javascript/jQuery solution would help, as you could detect the on('change') of the select and via ajax populate the corresponding content

Comment: ok let me just use jquery, i was trying to run away from that.. but anyway thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

few notes that I pick up...

1.) Don't ever use variable names like $s => easy to lost track and that name doesn't tell you what variable contain or do

2.) You're not passing selected value to reclusive function (missing third parameter)

Otherwise looks like this are working code.

Comment: *Don't ever use variable names like $s*: that's completely opinion based... and within a short function, using it as a local variable, it is more than readable for others who go through your code

Comment: When i'm going to read your code i need to figure out what variable does... that's called bad practice. Believe me.... if he named as selectedVariable you don't have to do that.